# Design patterns usually have duplicate tags

Tags: discussion, tags

There seem to be a lot of cases where, for a given design pattern, there's both [foo](/questions/tagged/foo) and [foo-pattern](/questions/tagged/foo-pattern):

1. [repository-pattern](/questions/tagged/repository-pattern) and [repository](/questions/tagged/repository)
2. [factory-pattern](/questions/tagged/factory-pattern) and [factory](/questions/tagged/factory)
3. [strategy-pattern](/questions/tagged/strategy-pattern) and [strategy](/questions/tagged/strategy)
4. [observer-pattern](/questions/tagged/observer-pattern) and [observer](/questions/tagged/observer)
5. [visitor-pattern](/questions/tagged/visitor-pattern) and [visitor](/questions/tagged/visitor)
6. [command-pattern](/questions/tagged/command-pattern) and [command](/questions/tagged/command) (latter not always the command pattern, but [Thinking About Using Command Design Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016095/thinking-about-using-command-design-pattern) is, so it's an ambiguous tag that needs attention anyway)
7. [specification-pattern](/questions/tagged/specification-pattern) and [specification](/questions/tagged/specification) (latter not always about the pattern, but [Specification Pattern and Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497277/specification-pattern-and-performance) is, so it's an ambiguous tag that needs attention anyway)
8. [facade-pattern](/questions/tagged/facade-pattern) and [facade](/questions/tagged/facade)
9. [builder-pattern](/questions/tagged/builder-pattern) and [builder](/questions/tagged/builder)
10. and lots more, including [null-object-pattern](/questions/tagged/null-object-pattern) and [null-object](/questions/tagged/null-object)

Though there are tags where there isn't duplication, because it isn't a design pattern, such as [url-pattern](/questions/tagged/url-pattern).

The tags either ought to be merged, or the difference between the two documented. For example "[foo](/questions/tagged/foo) is about the foo library, not about the foo pattern, which is [foo-pattern](/questions/tagged/foo-pattern)."

I asked about [observer-pattern](/questions/tagged/observer-pattern) versus [observer](/questions/tagged/observer) in [Difference between the observer and observer-pattern tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110476/difference-between-the-observer-and-observer-pattern-tags) .